# backup sql server 2008 and restore to sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm maintaining a few projects for different customers. Some of them user Sql Server 2005 and others use 2008.

On my dev-machine, I can only install one of them (2005 is OK for both in development).

However , If I need backup 2008 database back to my machine, it can not be restore to 2005.

I wonder how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a technical point of view, you can definitely install **two** instances of SQL Server (even different versions) on a single machine:

- Install SQL Server 2008 as default instance and access it as `(local)`
- Install SQL Server 2005 as `SQL2005` instance and access it as `(local)\SQL2005`

Either do this, or get a second machine (physical or virtual)